# BaaS for Google App Engine/J

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mbaas

There are lots of Backend-as-a-Server (BaaS) that are open source like:

- Usergrid
- BaasBox

However I have not seen any that is made with GAE/J. I tried doing a quick port of Usergrid as it is the most mature open source BaaS I see. however it is very dependent on Cassandra and Hazelcast as far as my porting is concerned.

Are there any BaaS made for the GAE platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is one in python which comes closer but not as a full fledged BaaS, [appengine-rest-server](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server)

Comment: +1 do you know any Java based rest server do the same?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old question but keeping it updated answer I Just want share my thoughts,

Around June 5, 2013 Google released support for Mbaas for GAE with **[Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com)** . I'm really surprised to know this because google already released it's own [Mobile Backend Starter](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter), It's good news to know that google have plan allow thirdparty app backend, Thanks Google!.

[image]

Image source Kinvey

Note:
*Hopefully it doesn't happen like Google reader disaster! I recommend using any opensource Mbaas because what to do if they suddenly stop the this service?.*